# How do I know the total number of steps while training using Tensorflow Object Detection API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection

I've been running a training job for the last 3 hours on GPU powered cloud machine with the following command:

```
python legacy/train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
```

and after running that, the log says this for example:

```
 INFO:tensorflow:global step 14455: loss = 0.5896 (0.775 sec/step)
I1001 19:27:43.575182 140054916601600 tf_logging.py:116] global step 14455: loss = 0.5896 (0.775 sec/step)
```

How do I know how many steps are there to be done or how many steps are there in total?

Comment: i am using object_detection/model_main_tf2.py to train,  There is an option flag --num_train_steps. e,g,    --num_train_steps==6000 means to execute 6000 steps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a pre-defined model topology, you look up the training period (in epochs or steps) in the documentation that comes with the model.  If you've made your own model, you determine the training period by watching the test results.  When the accuracy reaches an acceptable level and then starts to drop, you're likely over-training.  Back up to the high point of accuracy.  Repeat this experiment a few times to determine the "sweet spot" for your model.

Answer (score 0):

In the `ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config` it says in [line 163](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/samples/configs/ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config):

```
num_steps: 200000
```

This is the number of total steps, the training script will perform if you did not make any changes.